# Passing lists of properties of generic type to function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on an extension to Entity Framework Core for bulk operations. I have created a BulkInsert method that works well:

```
public static void BulkInsert<T>(this DbContext ctx, List<T> list, bool identityInsert = false, int batchSize=1000)
```

Now, I'm working on a method for BulkInsertOrUpdate. I would like the method signature to look something like this:

```
public static void BulkInsertOrUpdate<T>(this DbContext ctx, List<T> list, List<TProperty> columnsToMatch, List<TProperty> columnsToUpdate, bool identityInsert = false, int batchSize=1000)
```

I made up the "TProperty" - not sure that even exists. I've done some research and found a number of solutions for passing properties using lamda expressions - typically in some usage such as specifying an "order by" column for sorting a list of generic typed objects. Maybe I'm not being creative enough, but I haven't come up with a solution that would allow me to apply that approach here. I could just pass lists of strings and then check the lists against the properties of the generic class at runtime, but that isn't very developer-friendly. Any ideas?

Sample Usage: Suppose I have a database called FooDB. Inside of FooDB I have a table called Person. I am merging a list of Person records from some source. Some of the records may be new, others may be existing records that need to be updated. In this case, I want to look up the record by combination of FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth. If a record exists with the same FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth combination, I will update the Address, City, State, Zip on the existing record. Otherwise, I will insert a new record. I would want to call my function something like this...

```
fooDbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(listOfPersonRecords, new List<IProperty>(){Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.DateOfBirth}, new List<IProperty>(){Person.Address, Person.City, Person.State, Person.Zip});
```

Note: In creating this example, I came to the realization that I am probably not looking for TProperty, but for IProperty... but, how do I specify that the IProperty values need to be properties of class T?

Comment: Highly recommend to use third party tool like entityframework core extension.

Comment: I would assume you want each column to have different types, but there is no way in c# to express variable number of generic type arguments. So you would need some other workaround.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't quite clear enough. I'll add a sample usage... Also, I am currently using the efcore.bulkextensions extension that is currently available on nuget, but it has some limitations that I am trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the following signature:

```cs
public static void BulkInsertOrUpdate<T>(this DbContext ctx, List<T> list, 
    Expression<Func<T, object>> columnsToMatch, 
    Expression<Func<T, object>> columnsToUpdate, 
    bool identityInsert = false, int batchSize=1000)
{
    var toMatch = EnumProperties(columnsToMatch.Body).ToList();
    var toUpdate = EnumProperties(columnsToUpdate.Body).ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> EnumProperties(Expression expr)
{
    while (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
    {
        expr = ((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand;
    }

    switch (expr.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.New:
        {
            var ne = (NewExpression)expr;
            foreach (var argument in ne.Arguments)
            foreach (var property in EnumProperties(argument))
            {
                yield return property;
            }

            break;
        }

        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
        {
            if (((MemberExpression)expr).Member is PropertyInfo property)
                yield return property;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
ctx.BulkInsertOrUpdate(someItems, x => new { x.Key1, x.Key2 }, x => new { x.Field1, x.Filed2 });
```

Comment: I believe this would actually pass the values of the properties specified, no? I want to pass the actual properties - not the values of the properties.

Comment: It will generate NewExpression, which you can analyse.

Comment: I have updated answer with sample.

Comment: This appears to work. I don't quite understand the EnumProperties function, but I'll study it to make sure I do.

Comment: Well, this is just experience achieved during `linq2db` developing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void BulkInsertOrUpdate<T, TProperty>(this DbContext ctx,
        List<T> list, List<TProperty> columnsToMatch, List<TProperty> columnsToUpdate,
        bool identityInsert = false, int batchSize = 1000)
    {

    }
```

Is this what you are looking for?

You can have more than one generic type in a function (`T` and `TProperty` in this case).

While we are at it, why not add a [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) like so:

```
    public static void BulkInsertOrUpdate<T, TProperty>(this DbContext ctx,
        List<T> list, List<TProperty> columnsToMatch, List<TProperty> columnsToUpdate,
        bool identityInsert = false, int batchSize = 1000)
           where T : class where TProperty : class
```

Comment: Maybe... it at least gives me a bit more to research. I know I can specify that T is a class. Now I need to figure out how to specify that TProperty is a Property of class T.

Comment: @CMGeek if you explain in more detail I may be able to help you... Do you want to use reflection? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is the same as a SQL "merge" statement. I'll bulk load the data into a temporary table. Using the sample that I added to the question, I would first create a temporary table (let's call it temp_Person) and bulk insert the data into that table. Then, I would ultimately generate a merge statement that looks like "MERGE Person as tgt USING temp_Person as src ON (tgt.FirstName = src.FirstName ...) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.Address = ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ..."

Comment: Everything you have mentioned are implemented in [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), including Merge and Temporary table creation and BulkCopy into into it.

Comment: Not looking for a third party library

Comment: CMGeek what @Svya suggested is part of .NET, not a third party library

Comment: @ThomasBonini, actually it is third party library.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: oh, my bad, I didn't read the `linq2db` part and just assumed it was part of EF!